# Intermediate Certification Expiration trust issues between OS's

Tags: linux, windows, ssl-certificate

I recently had a intermediate certificate expire on my network. The sysadmins were able to push a GPO out to the Windows Servers with the new certificate chain and it restored Windows to Windows communication between servers without a reboot. However the Linux servers were still seeing the expired certificate chain when I ran

```sh
openssl s_client -connect intranet1.example.com:443
```

and were not able to successfully curl to the servers without ssl errors.

I tried restarting IIS and still presented the same problems. The only thing that corrected the intermediate certificate store for Linux was fully rebooting the Windows Servers.

It seems like Windows should not require a reboot to fix the certificate chain because Windows to Windows communication was restored without one. Is there something fundamentally different with how Linux and Windows validate certificate chains between each other and if they have had successful communication before they use those old certificate chains?

Any insight or recommended reading to understanding certificate chains between Linux and Windows would be appreciated.